# Stop animating once it meets certain condition - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, margin

I want to stop the scroll from animating once it matches particular condition.

Here I have

```
var $box2 = $('.column'),
    Width = max_x,
    cursor = 0;
var Width = $("#column").width();
console.log(divWidth)


$("#right-button").click(function () {
    if (cursor != Width && Width >= divWidth) {
        $box2.animate({
            marginLeft: "-=100"
        }, "fast");

        cursor += 300;
    }
});
```

I am animating the scroller to - 0r +300 depends on the click. And I want to write a condition here something like the current width is greater than the total width, stop animating.

Tried with if `cursor != totalWidth && totalWidth >= divWidth && this.width > totalWidth` , but not working. How to find the current width when it is animating? What should I do here?

Comment: Please post the html fragment your code manipulates.

Answer (score 0):

Try using step callback:

```
$box2.animate({
    marginLeft: "-=100"
}, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        if (cursor != totalWidth && totalWidth >= divWidth) $(this).stop();
    }
}, "fast");
```

Comment: No. It`s not working bro... I can still able to scroll after the current width.

Comment: You should post your relevant code in a jsfiddle, to hard to see what you are looking for...

Comment: Ok. just keeping it simple. I need scrolling up to some width(totalWidth`s width). Any method to do that.. ? tracing the width everytime the margin goes to -100..

Comment: << I need scrolling up to some width >> Sorry, i don't understand what you mean. If you post relevant code, maybe i could understand.